# Como ordenar um combo select pelo texto das options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Desejo ordenar um combo select do `HTML` em ordem alfabética e gostaria de ajuda na lógica para conseguir montar uma função que faça isso independente do numero de elementos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function NASort(a, b) {    
    if (a.innerHTML == 'NA') {
        return 1;   
    }
    else if (b.innerHTML == 'NA') {
        return -1;   
    }       
    return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
};

$('select option').sort(NASort).appendTo('select');


<select>
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Bus</option>
    <option value="3">NA</option>
    <option value="4">Bike</option>
    <option value="5">Tractor</option>
    <option value="6">NA</option>
    <option value="7">A</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bvVz/)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670041/sort-options-in-a-select-list-with-javascript-jquery-but-not-alphabetically)

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar o `Array.prototype.sort()`:

```js
function ordenar() {
    var itensOrdenados = $('#itens option').sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $('#itens').html(itensOrdenados);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itens">
    <option value="2">Maçã</option>
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="3">Laranja</option>
    <option value="8">Uva</option>
    <option value="5">Amora</option>
    <option value="15">Melão</option>
</select>
<button onclick="ordenar()">Ordenar</button>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, apesar do tópico ser antigo, me ajudou muito! Só uma coisa: nesse exemplo, o valor que aparece pro usuário após a ordenação, é o último da lista ("Uva", no caso). Como fazer pra o valor a aparecer após a ordenação ser o primeiro ("Amora", no caso)?

Comment: Basta inverter o valor de retorno da função `sort` : `return a.text < b.text ? 1 : -1;`.