# Ordenar Dropdown com jquery após append

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, order-by

Caso o usuário não encontre o item desejado na lista do `dropdown`, ele pode incluir um novo item, para isto utilizei a função `prompt`do `javascript`, e então o usuário digita o nome e clicando em `Ok`, caso o objeto não esteja realmente cadastrado no banco(As vezes por falta de não ter prestado a atenção, e não encontramos o item na lista), o objeto é cadastrado. Após o cadastro o objeto é adicionado à lista, porém ele vai pro final dela.

Então queria que após o `.append()`, fosse feito uma ordenação do objeto novamente, deixando ele na posição que seria ideal(em ordem alfabética).

Para isso pensei em criar um script que buscasse no banco todos os itens(de novo)e fosse inserido novamente, mas acho que seja um desperdício de código.
Este é o `script` utilizado

```
   $('#NewBrand').click(function () {
        var name;
        name = prompt("Qual a marca?");
        var url = '@Url.Action("CreateBrand", "Ajax")';
        if (name != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { name: name },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Name == name) {
                        alert("A mcarca " + name + " foi cadastrado com sucesso!");
                        $('#Brand').append('<option value="' + data.BrandID + '">' + data.Name + '</option>');
                    } else if (data == false) {
                        alert("Não foi possível cadastrar a marca " + name + "!");
                    } else {
                        alert("A marca " + data.Name + " já está cadastrada");
                    }
                }
            });
        }//if
    });
```

e aqui o `Dropdownlist` da `View`:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Tipo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EquipmentTypelID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",id="Type", style = "float:left;" })<div class="btn btn-primary" id="NewType" title="Novo Tipo" style="float:left;">+</div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipmentTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Existe alguma maneira de ordenar diretamente pela `View`?

Comment: Por que duplicata? eu já tinha visto esta pergunta, mas não entendi nada.

Comment: É uma possível duplicata, pois as respostas geradas aqui serão parecidas com a que está na pergunta do link. Porém, isso é apenas minha opinião.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar uma função para fazer isso e chamar após o `append()`. [Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278089/4843158) possui vários exemplos de como fazer isso.

```js
function OrdenarSelect() {
  var selElem = document.getElementById('EquipmentTypelID');
  var tmpAry = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < selElem.options.length; i++) {
    tmpAry[i] = new Array();
    tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
    tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
  }
  tmpAry.sort();
  while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
    selElem.options[0] = null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpAry.length; i++) {
    var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
    selElem.options[i] = op;
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="OrdenarSelect()">Ordenar</button>
<select id="EquipmentTypelID">
  <option value='22'>Opção 4</option>
  <option value='101'>Opção 2</option>
  <option value='1'>Opção 3</option>
  <option value='-2'>Opção 1</option>
</select>
```

Para utilizar em seu código, basta chamar a função passando após inserir o elemento com o `.append()`, desta forma:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.Name == name) {
        alert("A mcarca " + name + " foi cadastrado com sucesso!");
        $('#Brand').append('<option value="' + data.BrandID + '">' + data.Name + '</option>');
         OrdenarSelect(); //Função aqui
    } else if (data == false) {
        alert("Não foi possível cadastrar a marca " + name + "!");
    } else {
        alert("A marca " + data.Name + " já está cadastrada");
    }
}
```

Outra opção, que garante a validação no `server`, é retornar uma `PartialView` com todo o `DropDownList` e apenas substituir. Dependendo da quantidade de itens, pode ser uma boa ou péssima opção. Mas tudo depende de seu contexto.

Dicas de leituras:

- [Como ordenar um combo select pelo texto das options?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64498/20615)
- [Ordenando select em ordem alfábetica com jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88937/20615)

Comment: como faço para chamar a função após o append?

Comment: @FabioSouza Depois dessa parte `$('#Brand').append('<option value="' + data.BrandID + '">' + data.Name + '</option>');`, basta colocar `OrdenarSelect();`. Isso se tiver feito a função da mesma forma.

Comment: esta linha ´var selElem = document.getElementById('EquipmentTypelID');´ o id é dos itens da lista ou é do objeto (dropdown)?

Comment: @FabioSouza No lugar de **EquipmentTypelID** você coloca o ID do seu DropDownList

Answer (score 4):

Você pode ordenar salvar os valores dos `options` em um array e então ordená-lo. Quando é usado somente o `.sort()` sem argumentos, ele já entende ascendente e por ordem alfabética.

Um exemplo:

```js
const array = [];

function adicionar() {
  array.push($("#novo").val());
  
  $("#Brand").children('option').each(function() {
    $('#Brand').html('');
    array.sort();
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      $('#Brand').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
    });
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Brand">
  <option />
</select>

<br>
<input id="novo" />
<button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
```

Comment: o Array, neste caso está sendo o vetor que está armazenando a lista de itens certo? bom no meu caso, como vou puxar uma lista do banco, e caso não tenha o valor será inserido, meu array teria que trazer a informação do banco certo?

Comment: O Array é a variável array. Na verdade não @FabioSouza, quando o select for carregado pelo banco, ele vai possuir o conteúdo..esse laço pega tudo que JÁ está la dentro, mais o que foi inserido e ordena. A única coisa que terá ter atenção, é quais atributos preencher dentro do laço (como value, id, etc).

Comment: Acho que entendi. Mais tarde vou tentar... Valeu por enquanto

Comment: `array.push($("#novo").val());` está linha não seria para adicionar o que digitar no array?

Comment: @FabioSouza, sim, isso mesmo, por isso ela está fora do laço - após a adição é que é feita a ordenação.